# What is the approach for autocompletion of links in CKEditor5?

Tags: wysiwyg, 10

I have a new install of Drupal 10 with CKEditor 5 enabled, and I thought that CKEditor 5 now provided autocompletion of links, as used to be provided by the Linkit module. However, whenever I try to use the Link button, I get the 'Link URL' box shown below, but never any autocompletion suggestions no matter how many characters I type.

What is the correct method to get this working?

Comment: Are there browser console errors?

Comment: @cilefen yes there are I have added them to the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time I write this, it is necessary to install and enable LinkIt on desired text formats in Drupal 10 to enable this feature. Yes, there is a Core issue to bring LinkIt features into Core but that is incomplete.

Comment: I was afraid you were going to say that, as I cannot get LinkIt to work either... the Linkit button never appears in CKEditor. I will open a separate question for this! Thanks for your input.

Comment: There is no linkit button. You enable it on the text format. It enhances the default button.

Comment: I have now uninstalled and reinstalled Linkit and got it working. I think that previously I was using the wrong text format to edit the text, a text format which had not had a Linkit profile enabled. All working now. Thank you for your time.

Comment: (There was historically a separate Linkit button for the editor, which confused me when searching the documentation.)